# Jetpack Compose: Controlling NestedScroll Behavior with LazyColumn and BottomSheetScaffold

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I'm developing with Jetpack Compose, and I have a question about nestedScroll behavior.

I've placed a lazyColumn inside the BottomSheetScaffold's sheetContent.

However, when I scroll the lazyColumn downwards, the scroll propagates to the parent BottomSheet, causing it to scroll and disappear.

What I want to achieve is that when scrolling downwards, only the lazyColumn should scroll initially, and after the lazyColumn has reached the top, further scrolling should make the BottomSheet disappear.

My code like this:

```
BottomSheetScaffold(
  scaffoldState = state,
  sheetDragHandle = {},
  sheetContent = {
     LazyColumn(
         modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()
                            .nestedScroll(// do someting?),
     ){
      // some content
    }
  }
){}
```

How can I achieve this behavior? Your assistance is appreciated.

I tried to use `onPostScroll`, but it is not woking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the intended behaviour. Firstly `lazyColumn` scrolls and finally the `BottomSheet` moves. Try to use the `fillMaxSize()` of the `lazyColumn`. **If you touch something else other than lazyColumn then BottomSheet is going to move.**

It's hard to say anything else with so little code you provided.